# Как обернуть в функцию tress в node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как можно обернуть в функцию tress в node js и возвращать готовый результат из нее?
Есть такой код

```
var result=[];
     var q = tress(function (URL, callback) {
        needle.get(URL, options, function (err, res, id) {
          тут происходит парсинг
          result.push(..);
        });

    });

    q.drain = function () {
       console.log(result);
    };

    q.push(URL);
```

Хотелось бы это все обернуть в функцию и по завершение tress возвращать готовый результат.

Примерно так

```
function test(){
   var q = tress(function (URL, callback) {
    needle.get(URL, options, function (err, res, id) {
      тут происходит парсинг
      result.push(..);
    });

   });

   q.drain = function () {
     console.log(result);
   };

   q.push(URL);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Попытался так сделать,но возвращает пустой массив

Comment: Промисифицируйте ее и возвращайте промис

Comment: Можно пример,если не сложно?